# Removing sinusoidal oscillation from signal Python

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, fft

[image]

Any suggestion for removing sinusoidal oscillation from such a signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use low-pass filter. Take a look here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html

or even better here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html

`filtfilt` function applies filter twice, from the beginning, and from the end, so that delay that occurs due to filtering is removed (two opposite delays eliminate each other)

you will need to adjust filter parameters, most important - `cut-off frequency` (set order of the filter to 5-10), try different values around 0.05-0.2.

```
sig = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] # your signal
b, a = signal.butter(8, 0.1)
filtered_signal = signal.filtfilt(b, a, sig, method="gust")
```